# How to export a table with spicific rows name from Excel by Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to export rows from Excel file with the specific name of the rows in the first cell by Matlab. Here is a (very) simplified version of my table:
Note:the interesting rows named with a

```
Column1       Column2    Column3  
____          ____       ____

 a             1           5
 b             2           3        
 c             4           5    
 a             3           2
```

Answer (score 1):

### [m,b]=xlsread('filename.xls');

### colhead=b(1,2:end);

### rowhead=b(2:end,1);

### inrow='a';

### incol='Column2';

### irow=strmatch(inrow,rowhead);

### icol=strmatch(incol,colhead);

### m(irow,icol);